# CMakeSettings.json environment variables aren't passed to CMake using the Visual Studio generators

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

In a Visual Studio CMake project, I have a CMakeSettings.json file with an environment variable that I'd like to use within CMakeLists.txt:

```
{
    "environments": [
        {
            "TestDir": "C:\\Test\\Directory"
        }
    ],
        {
            "name": "x64-[generator]",
            "generator": "[generator]",
            "configurationType": "Debug",
            "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],
            "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
            "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
            "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
            "buildCommandArgs": "",
            "ctestCommandArgs": ""
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Note that I use `[generator]` as a placeholder for brevity to represent the varying generators. I believe that I've followed Microsoft's reference correctly for defining a custom environment variable (found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=msvc-160#custom-environment-variables).

I tested this with a simple message command (can also use the "Environment settings" CMake output line):

```
message("Environment Variable: $ENV{TestDir}")
```

Using the Unix Makefile and Ninja generators resulted in the expected output (C:\Test\Directory) but fails when using the Visual Studio generators. Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that's limited to the CMakeSettings.json file (or really any solution that doesn't require editing the CMakeLists files).